# By looking at an Android source code, determine packets sent out protocol

Tags: applications, networking

is there a way by looking at the android application source code, or manifest file, I can determine what is the network protocol support for that particular application? or is it more of whether the android version supports it. For example, is it possible to see if an application does not support TLS v1.2 etc?

As far as I know, from the android API, there is a practice where people use network_security_configuration where it contains a method *cleartextTrafficPermitted=["true" | "false"]>*. This restricts accidental usage of clear text traffic if traffic is tunneled through a proxy.

Another alternative is if the application implements the socket by himself by doing SSLSocketFactory.

My intent is to move towards analysis of the mobile application packets if they are encrypted. I understand wireshark or any packet capturing application can work; i am just exploring different possibilities.